# Function execution doesn't always print to console

Tags: r, function

An R function will automatically return the last expression.  I assumed that these functions `f` and `g` would be equivalent.  However, they have different behavior in the console.  `f` doesn't print anything (!) and silently returns `10`.

How can I understand this?  I've been using R for years and this has me scratching my head.

I often use the console to debug and it's confusing and frustrating when I can't rely on the function output printing to console.

```r
f <- function(x) a <- 10
g <- function(x) 10

f() # doesn't print anything!
print(f())
#> [1] 10

g() # prints
#> [1] 10
print(g())
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute `a <- 10` at the console it doesn't print anything. It's no different if it's the last statement in a function.

This works because function results can be marked as "invisible" so they don't print, and the assignment function `<-` does that.  You can do it in your own function by calling `invisible(result)` explicitly.

To make things visible, the simplest way is to put the value in parentheses.  For example, `(a <- 10)` will return a visible result as well as making the assignment to `a`.  Same with `(f())` in your example.